# Understanding a meaning of 処遇

Tags: meaning, words

I found the word in an anime quite some time ago, and I wanted to finally confirm if I understood its meaning.

From the 新明解, the definition is:

> 人をある立場から評価して、しかるべき地位を与えること。

The context in which I found this is:

> （千束）これ 見たでしょ？取引時間 間違えてた　指令部のせいです～。楠木さんにだって 責任あるでしょう？ 
> （楠木）他人の**処遇**を気にする前に もっと働いてほしいもんだがな。遊びで お前にライセンス 出してるわけじゃないんだぞ。

Could the 「地位を与えること」 part be understood as "telling people what to do" in this case? Or is it more something like "judging people"? Or could this meaning just "assuming a certain attitude", as in this example sentence 「冷たい―を受ける」?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[地位](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%9C%B0%E4%BD%8D) means social position/status, and しかるべき地位を与える means placing someone in an appropriate social position/status.
If it's from [this novel](https://syosetu.org/novel/307082/3.html), this 他人 refers to Takina, and 他人の処遇 refers to the decision to kick her out of DA after [the "命令違反" episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Re_y-W_DTwg). So this 処遇 is about a demotion rather than a promotion in this case, but it's still about someone's position in an organization.

> 他人の処遇を気にする前に もっと働いてほしいもんだがな。
>
> I wish you would work more before worrying about the treatment of someone else (=Takina).

Comment: Thank you, the series is right.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's more like "putting people in their (proper) place". So definitely closer to "judging people".

> しかるべき地位を与えること 
> To give them their proper (social) position/status.